# Joomla 3.3 and Google SEO Question

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, google-analytics

Google is indexing my mobile menu along with my sites main menu and when I check Google it's displaying duplicates. I'm not sure why this is happening but I'd like to stop Google from indexing the sidebar menu at all and only index the main menu.

I'm worried if Google thinks it's duplicate content, Google will kill my site. I'm using Yootheme Stage theme if that help any.

How can I force Google to forget the Sidebar (mobile) menu? I have submitted a sitemap with only the main menu but I'm not sure that worked.

Comment: I have figured it out. I had  to no index, no follow each individual menu item. Hoping this works. Joomla should look to have that option at the top level for each menu.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the robots.txt file in the root to exclude urls from (Google) indexing

> Disallow: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23&Itemid=377
>   Disallow: /index.php?Itemid=377

*Depending on your server you should leave out the leading slash /*

You will have to update robots.txt each time you change (sub)menu items...

So here are more methods:
http://moz.com/blog/12-ways-to-keep-your-content-hidden-from-the-search-engines